# Ruby on Rails 4 text_tag in HAML incorrect output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a form I'm marking up in HAML. Attempting to add the following `text_field` is not working proper.

```
= text_field :gamedate, {:id => 'datepicker'}
```

This ends up with the following HTML:

```
<input id="gamedate_{:id=>"datepicker"}" type="text" name="gamedate[{:id=>"datepicker"}]">
```

How do I just get a name and id of `gamedate` -- the output above looks broken and I'm guessing that I'm using `text_field` incorrectly. This isn't tied to a model of any sort, I'm using `form_tag` and not `form_for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `text_field_tag`.

```
= text_field :gamedate, 'defaultvaluehere', :id => 'datepicker'
```

Answer (score 2):

It is working corrctly. You want:

```
= text_field nil, :gamedate, id: 'datepicker'
```

or better

```
= text_field_tag :gamedate, id: 'datepicker'
```

Read: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field